# Sending a String from Node Js to a component React Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am using Node Js and React Js to send data from node to a React component but the state never change in the console when i did response.json() i get my string sent but in my component it's empty and there is no data .
Here is my Node js code  :

```
app.post('/try', function(req, res) {
  results='hello everybody !'
  res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

And here's my React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: null };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const data = new FormData();

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/try',{

      method: 'POST',
      body : data
    })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();

        } // if the response is a JSON object
      ).then(
      success =>console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
    ).catch(
      error => null // Handle the error response object
    )
      .then(results => {
          this.setState({ results: results });
          console.log(results)

      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Users">
      <h1>results</h1>
      <div>this is my result: {this.state.results}</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the second .then is not returning anything try to return the success which is the value of response.json

Comment: when i try response.json at any .then it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, results is string, you dont have to convert it to string again,

```
results='hello everybody !'
```

then, in react you are not using the proper way of thens. Please try the below code.

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/try', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  response.json().then((result)=>this.setState({ results: results }))
} 
.catch(
  error => null // Handle the error response object
```

)

Comment: :) Glad to help you.

Comment: Can i ask u an other question ? if i want to send an other string like this others="hello i am asma" i tried to change this line : response.json().then((results,others)=>this.setState({ results: results,others:others }))   but it doesn't show the value of the string

Comment: nope,  results will always have what ever you send. that is, results param in the .then will have the response object. so do a console.log of your results object and then setstate accordingly

Comment: i mean like this   :  results='hello everybody !' , others="hello i am asma "

Comment: send like, results={first:'hello everybody !',others:"hello i am asma "};res.send(JSON.stringify(results)); and then in the react, use .then((results)=>console.log(results)), now you can see both the strings in console and then setstate accordingly

Comment: yup it's working thank u soo much and sorry for bothering u . Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert the normal string to JSON.

eg.

```
var result = "hello everybody !"
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // ""hello everybody !""
```

This is not a JSON

Try this way

```
var result = {"data" :"hello everybody !"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // "{"data":"hello everybody !"}"
```